# Can greengrass be run in my data center

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

We have a requirement where we want to run AWS GreenGrass on our VM in our own data center which will not have connectivity with AWS IoT. Thought is to have similar cloud and on-premise solution(behind a firewall). We want to reuse the cloud solution, which has lambda functions in AWS GreenGrass. Wanted to know if it is possible to run AWS GreenGrass without AWS IoT? Any insight would be of great help.

Comment: For initial setup, Greengrass core needs to connect to AWS Greengrass services in the cloud and if you need to push changes to the on-premise device which is Greengrass core is running on, it needs connection to the cloud as well. Once everything is setup, it can be run without connecting to the cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the hardware requirements of Greengrass and you can find more information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/faqs/?nc1=h_ls).
For defining the Greengrass configuration for first time, you need to connect your Greengrass to AWS IoT by deploying, after that you can run Greengrass without any AWS IoT connectivity. But Consider that the deployment of serverless functions (Lambda functions) will be done through AWS IoT. You can find more information about Greengrass [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/what-is-gg.html).